# Construct AND query if parameter is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I'm allowing my user to search by 10 different criteria. I'm picking that from url. But problem is if some of that criteria is/are empty. Then it will search record in database where is empty record.

```
$pretrazi_drzava=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_drzava"]);
$pretrazi_broj=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_broj"]);
$pretrazi_spol=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_spol"]);
$pretrazi_boja=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_boja"]);
$pretrazi_rasa=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_rasa"]);
$pretrazi_ime=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_ime"]);
$pretrazi_godina=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_godina"]);
$pretrazi_status=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_status"]);
$pretrazi_otac=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_otac"]);
$pretrazi_majka=quote_smart($_GET["pretrazi_majka"]);
```

It is easy to do with OR

```
...AND (mg_drzava.drzava='$pretrazi_drzava' 
                        OR mg_golub.brojgoluba='$pretrazi_broj' 
                        OR mg_golub.spol='$pretrazi_spol' 
                        OR mg_golub.boja='$pretrazi_boja' 
                        OR mg_golub.rasa='$pretrazi_rasa'
                        OR mg_golub.ime='$pretrazi_ime' 
                        OR mg_golub.godina='$pretrazi_godina'
                        OR mg_status.status='$pretrazi_status'
                        OR O.brojgoluba='$pretrazi_otac'
                        OR M.brojgoluba='$pretrazi_majka')...
```

But if instead OR u put AND and if for example only `mg_golub.brojgolub=''` is empty, then it will search every record in database where `brojgolub` is empty and it won't find nothing and it won't show nothing as result.

How to solve that situation?

Comment: Well, if it really IS empty, then what do you want to do with it?

Comment: This approach looks like one hell of a design failure ..

Comment: Functions like `quote_smart` are a very, very bad idea. Please, do not use these. Why aren't you using [SQL data placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid all of this in the first place? PDO's named parameters would clean this up significantly.

Comment: You should only append conditions to your query if the value in question is populated. Otherwise, omit that.

Comment: the person asking the question, does not even seem interested to hear the answer.

Comment: why design failure?

why are quote_smart bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a foreach and iterate the $_GET array for construct your SQL statement

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

if(count($_GET) > 0)
{
    // Append WHERE clause
    $sql .= " WHERE ";

    // Construct WHERE
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value != '')
        {
            $sql .= ' '.$key.' = '.$value.' AND ';
        }
    }


    // Remove last "AND"
    $sql = trim( $sql, 'AND ');

 }
```

I didn't test this code, is just for reference how to ignore a emtpy value in your SQL statement. hope this help.

Updated: avoid 1=1 in query

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the several conditions simultaneously, you need the AND parameter, like the gender is "male" AND the age is "35". If the user is not passing some of the parameters, it may mean he doesn't know them, or cares about them: the gender is male and i don't care about the age. If that is the case, you need to exclude that condition from your query, instead of using extra conditions that will only slow the query down.

Comment: that is helpful, but sometimes people want to search by different criteria, sometimes with AND, sometimes with OR

Answer (score 1):

if you want to skip the parameter if it's empty then

```
where (someparam1 is null or (someparam1 = somecolumn1)) 
and (someparam2 is null or (someparam2 = someColumn2) 
and ...
```

is a way you want to go.

if quotesmart always returns a string, then

```
where ((someparam1 = '') or (someparam1 = somecolumn1)) 
and ((someparam2 = '') or (someparam2 = someColumn2) 
and ...
```

if you don't want to put unneeded parameters in the sql, then generate a list/hash of selected parameters and build a parameterised sql statement from it, and set the parameters values.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use

```
AND (b.a='' OR b.a='$a')
```

instead.

Comment: What is `b`?  I don't see that in the original question.